# Vega Lite Repeat Charts and Labeling

Tags: vega-lite, vega

[See code here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-deNZTw2GfWmhzlCq9066m21hJ+W2OzcdcCnObbrsot0FR1xuIB7ljlbz-K1eN+gqUOH8bQ695nu7EAr2SYAmw9i5MeNx8iKfy3PcTZICYxhBuCkIDJEmSlHUhQlDkZQAELVLU+SFE0ZC4YsHTdL0txzEMow3tEmBTHMVHzLRGZLCsLzTDWWxiMSILTMiICnOccCXC6dzQk8LwCt8nzTJqAoAkC7YlqOuxKLCZDwoiyrUiY8ZusMEnfFsEZ6ZKgzQXpzoMtMvwsgWK7xhIpY-AJo5NhKLwbDq5byjZM62r8tw-KaDqGty7aqkcmoHGC4XWi8RI6glAX5uyXrxiqXTTDxhYCumobSQcBw3jGcaRQmiH7ASo56dOHYHJC8khSu678sMuWDGWe76ge05ukyOojH0pa9pg04gqqxJavxC7WWuYGBTK4J3KVHL+YtVYbgJDaipG7J9U6W0nm6tp-gMOq5Ted45gyRJLkGOJvh+SzfmdMpiEyfzsisiTrlNhwjPOOxKHBxiDKaLJbJsqEgFkOQYS4WHlAAwvhSPoMRZToyiSwUX0ILUQsdGTC4fQEMxNFkcswFJZsAz5Ucr5CWcFxXDc2qPM8NyEm656Ur9ynKkWuyATCcIIhDekGZsgpfYzeLmdJRJNhOAUbpZBViMKTmVdljOqUGK6StsSsbauSobocMqar8sr7hFPIqmykamjqh1WpKEbxY7h5eg+LLjVlNaXaaX05eNYZ-GWZVsLGIcQkGhZFoJE7Th88n8TrAqefKk1y98hIjIJR1wA1Z6EjruJNidD7gsXu53AtfZLW6AyjR387NxbR5Vm67vbCCX0O2XfenZ8AuMyz4y3S6+aRn+7wvQEb13aeOJ4mIW9Nn9oFVoMZ63PWl1Wco8HtvWNdTaOcMI7khHI6UZQACIY4-WPNFUePkegFNEyxMYEwGLk0osTVin5aaShhocSMuwSwO2EuzcSZ8pLtgjFxXawp0yAmBMqRWHd0yaW0sYNOZJZbyQkvcYeysbjShbuJM8pp1QajGhbEOHdBiNgDHuLyaA5r2l7gHasi5fx5Q2AlWWIJixGVFPWBKkp5yDFSsI-MhUYgcJykZJc5sio3G+JHEA0Z44VR9O6UyEYugjnqktCQo0RyQw7m1JaKpkojh8n8BK04YZ2XVOCBcEjPStyrB8P84IAxlnTOrOugURQ8STOyTk48Hz7HVJeUaKjgkng3FqDuRxzy71vL4b8G4vjQQXEZFekD3rYk3qySMgi94NQkEnVaLNwbtmLEySElAeJ33Qh-Yoz8ACi796ifxInhH+LwQAUyDOAoB9FCgUxHAs6ZHE1g1h1MfYUhikGiQ5q8P83MKRWI3NBOypklJ4JHKKRsgTiFSwHDLSqA8hgCWJKyWhyo-h7miVbfkjZfhgmsewyqfIyxFlysuC2iidgOyScInaqdO78UkZVc5hNoIliJAozioVMnz0+BlDR+telGVZFDdR2AVbdjjgnMlRxfjvO+DYqsU0O6M12J1RJ+clobihJdURoKy7Tl9PcP4lja5ZP4R1L4ZYjJRLJMkn8VjLElxXCq-M84faig9GPGJG5Gx1jBJ4oxRSSmVznHZMUrhXpfnXm6GUo4Cy+yaS4lyEIGyCj3B0n5IURTrAOP0xGgyUZlAAGJjKIs0XGbFf4gCov0ampMQHoCTSslN8aoHSUMsfEKpomz7LEpzB2aDXjOtqSmUGRjhaDAhF9B5ksdJkPRK8zYw55xlO+QKN4DDjRvCsXsUUeseQtOHviUaYVYXeQXB6RFSoXaNh1HiL5fsQ7am9RCJkeL+HJUJYHD0mVwWqnPPJDuZq9GvAOr9WmDKzFGQOBSmF6c26bGYc+HdFsBrvqhLWeRfsxVH2gjs3i40gNPu1AKKkGZlUxMMkSNkm6EWbRlYFdUuVGytT9iqjcl0-iFmuuaueWIkwighMSQJ75V4OsYSFSyUJwRARAuuGG9xN5jjBhfV4BJwRsjPH0END9xlDOwgAcWjY0L+NMXBJo2Gs81SzZNzGGApyBGzXhGoJEMEeJw2YHPEhkkA5atTql6QVTU1yVL4iXEQ5t0tYNtp5HhrD2i0WOfJDcfJ-aZz1ldkMQRnJnLujZJecEfkaVrGCpqpFhdt4jlxeujFiYvVEmkfqr2LxOrToNUqQywcT2mlGmyALUdpI+UXPS0xUUWRJmJEXNl2TEzQvPNvQLfKqw+JfNIvEGX+pLQ+CfBLIxqUVwVfsXYWoGHtRWrlLugSF0TX5ZuSk84wM4cNb0vYwoDigtnsU9eRqdbqkupUu1NH3A1N3PlIsu5mP-RcXyHEQNdbnwhgBcL7pphCcxqJ8oAAJSTEzSLTJcGIXoCnxhKfQOD4san2J002SyGOEJXvFsOW8QSJmoPksJoY3BKkfj2w0vZ9sLznP8lOwuAUDsJwWRlIE-5jC9iLh1lCPO3okSU7iqKfEJtvIRna5bF0jUlFi-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-mzU73rEh2AUKC2AIEsJ7yH0RylETCam2F+HZHRxQXTBMxEPdHrSuVrRuXrBCimwli0ieV0g83jE1iZF4wJHZDp1pSVRpFi1cg9mLA5zAOa0Zh4mR35zQEFEvyEQBRFAjG0R8glyxDxDuG2AEl3VQFNDqg2zy0TBJTVxVBHD2AjgA1122GenNUNzJUjGLkuUay5190LF2EElwJPAgj-VtHVE9n6yoLsjW2YMCRiRhnC3lRGGm2WyGDSyDHNjYLfVLFXW3j-ytFw0fB+G5Xc32xqT1xG1kSqUkIfDxE7n913iL33myXWDWkpSYze0vh1gVU+A2HCAAF1IgjFfAkAnATB44EA0B0gbBEh9QvRCh6IGAEBKBcFehttttrAkAUgQAAAVD4gAfRRlJNRnUEwFJIAFlaSQA4YoBkSGBUSXB0TMS0EwZCSI04BrRSSAAFUSUkl+SKJklktk9ADkygVw-EwkgAVQAGUX5BThSI02BgJGSFBQBmTBAUSyYpSYgMTKB1NEduSXBFSlhSS1BSSiSVTRT9BnBxS9TWSDSQBpSJwjRzT0BFSyQRTYQcgRTuQnTtSkSXTJT3SjTMSgtIpvSQBG95R-SaBAyHSQydSJS3TpSy4vTlBCTUYrQkyUzgytT0zwzMyozKBj1MQ4yAAZGIQswQIMx0kssM-UtNSMzAY091XMOMkkkCUkgAOQFKJNJP+zYDRDTNbNdPbOlO7JgDmDEAAConC9g5SXAhyRyqSIBrgwSlBiBbBZBmSXRET-AjAlQdS2AkgEB5A0h4YBl6hQSNI2AMgETiSySKStyaT6TrBeT+ShTfAmzrAlSVT-zST1TNSlBLSOhrS2BbT7TizIK-SX4AzGzUzrAEyaTkLkzUKEKQB8yDwGymznAlA6zMKUKiKQBwS8Y4A8FMgaBlgTxUclB4AagsABxp1kBfAABrOIAwIwFwJgJAXwMYDUwQTAGgHAYIUIOAFEEINgLiwoAAYn0iQFGluFaDkoUqKHooPiUDYDcCgDoB5Hy33BkGEvQBwDYE5FEi1JAHLlsC8FkB8FQFACsBcuMxoGyBeFAFPLgCVBsEvIxPkAhL4sKHjkcsSFaHjhdBAExAhJ5FADMC8riF8v8t8GfNstCpcAAEcGBoTxL7BxLEQITbBBB444gEgkgwqoSnKdBwh6q4ZOKeL3Ksr0AhLgQ5RZBRIGgPAaBTg0AfggJLzxLJLUAQgwgQq6BBBjA9A4ALAYqNycZqSyh-yygUZrBSryr0AmAqrrBYT5RFStAEJAl9rMAShWKXR7gUJmK4ALqBw9glB7K2BHLnK9B4BYh3KkrBAZkNzKTqSxhDBChcr8q6AYgaBiq9RLytrErPLvqXB74kYARAaXBZA2AEBHBIqURdSZqMxYBEBCgdqwh45oSyA6r6q9zPKXz3Ltz0qFK0BZBWTBB6rwSgA/view)

I am working on a prototype dashboard and had fun so far building it with Vega Lite. However, I hit a road block on the following points:

1. I want to add a P10 and P90 line on all the bar charts. I have followed the [tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_precipitation_mean.html) for the single bar chart with line but I was not able to work it with repeat charts.
2. Adding labels on every single bar similar to this [tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/layer_bar_labels.html) but could not make it work with the repeat charts
3. I want to add a second pie chart which will be identical to the one I have except that the values will be multiplied with a constant. I tried a nested concat but it didn't work. The charts disappeared without an error.
4. I failed to replicate this [tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_bar_select_highlight.html) for selecting and higlighting and I would appreciate the help
5. Is it possible to add filtered data tables in Vega or Vega lite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [code here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-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-deNZTw2GfWmhzlCq9066m21hJ+W2OzcdcCnObbrsot0FR1xuIB7ljlbz-K1eN+gqUOH8bQ695nu7EAr2SYAmw9i5MeNx8iKfy3PcTZICYxhBuCkIDJEmSlHUhQlDkZQAELVLU+SFE0ZC4YsHTdL0txzEMow3tEmBTHMVHzLRGZLCsLzTDWWxiMSILTMiICnOccCXC6dzQk8LwCt8nzTJqAoAkC7YlqOuxKLCZDwoiyrUiY8ZusMEnfFsEZ6ZKgzQXpzoMtMvwsgWK7xhIpY-AJo5NhKLwbDq5byjZM62r8tw-KaDqGty7aqkcmoHGC4XWi8RI6glAX5uyXrxiqXTTDxhYCumobSQcBw3jGcaRQmiH7ASo56dOHYHJC8khSu678sMuWDGWe76ge05ukyOojH0pa9pg04gqqxJavxC7WWuYGBTK4J3KVHL+YtVYbgJDaipG7J9U6W0nm6tp-gMOq5Ted45gyRJLkGOJvh+SzfmdMpiEyfzsisiTrlNhwjPOOxKHBxiDKaLJbJsqEgFkOQYS4WHlAAwvhSPoMRZToyiSwUX0ILUQsdGTC4fQEMxNFkcswFJZsAz5Ucr5CWcFxXDc2qPM8NyEm656Ur9ynKkWuyATCcIIhDekGZsgpfYzeLmdJRJNhOAUbpZBViMKTmVdljOqUGK6StsSsbauSobocMqar8sr7hFPIqmykamjqh1WpKEbxY7h5eg+LLjVlNaXaaX05eNYZ-GWZVsLGIcQkGhZFoJE7Th88n8TrAqefKk1y98hIjIJR1wA1Z6EjruJNidD7gsXu53AtfZLW6AyjR387NxbR5Vm67vbCCX0O2XfenZ8AuMyz4y3S6+aRn+7wvQEb13aeOJ4mIW9Nn9oFVoMZ63PWl1Wco8HtvWNdTaOcMI7khHI6UZQACIY4-WPNFUePkegFNEyxMYEwGLk0osTVin5aaShhocSMuwSwO2EuzcSZ8pLtgjFxXawp0yAmBMqRWHd0yaW0sYNOZJZbyQkvcYeysbjShbuJM8pp1QajGhbEOHdBiNgDHuLyaA5r2l7gHasi5fx5Q2AlWWIJixGVFPWBKkp5yDFSsI-MhUYgcJykZJc5sio3G+JHEA0Z44VR9O6UyEYugjnqktCQo0RyQw7m1JaKpkojh8n8BK04YZ2XVOCBcEjPStyrB8P84IAxlnTOrOugURQ8STOyTk48Hz7HVJeUaKjgkng3FqDuRxzy71vL4b8G4vjQQXEZFekD3rYk3qySMgi94NQkEnVaLNwbtmLEySElAeJ33Qh-Yoz8ACi796ifxInhH+LwQAUyDOAoB9FCgUxHAs6ZHE1g1h1MfYUhikGiQ5q8P83MKRWI3NBOypklJ4JHKKRsgTiFSwHDLSqA8hgCWJKyWhyo-h7miVbfkjZfhgmsewyqfIyxFlysuC2iidgOyScInaqdO78UkZVc5hNoIliJAozioVMnz0+BlDR+telGVZFDdR2AVbdjjgnMlRxfjvO+DYqsU0O6M12J1RJ+clobihJdURoKy7Tl9PcP4lja5ZP4R1L4ZYjJRLJMkn8VjLElxXCq-M84faig9GPGJG5Gx1jBJ4oxRSSmVznHZMUrhXpfnXm6GUo4Cy+yaS4lyEIGyCj3B0n5IURTrAOP0xGgyUZlAAGJjKIs0XGbFf4gCov0ampMQHoCTSslN8aoHSUMsfEKpomz7LEpzB2aDXjOtqSmUGRjhaDAhF9B5ksdJkPRK8zYw55xlO+QKN4DDjRvCsXsUUeseQtOHviUaYVYXeQXB6RFSoXaNh1HiL5fsQ7am9RCJkeL+HJUJYHD0mVwWqnPPJDuZq9GvAOr9WmDKzFGQOBSmF6c26bGYc+HdFsBrvqhLWeRfsxVH2gjs3i40gNPu1AKKkGZlUxMMkSNkm6EWbRlYFdUuVGytT9iqjcl0-iFmuuaueWIkwighMSQJ75V4OsYSFSyUJwRARAuuGG9xN5jjBhfV4BJwRsjPH0END9xlDOwgAcWjY0L+NMXBJo2Gs81SzZNzGGApyBGzXhGoJEMEeJw2YHPEhkkA5atTql6QVTU1yVL4iXEQ5t0tYNtp5HhrD2i0WOfJDcfJ-aZz1ldkMQRnJnLujZJecEfkaVrGCpqpFhdt4jlxeujFiYvVEmkfqr2LxOrToNUqQywcT2mlGmyALUdpI+UXPS0xUUWRJmJEXNl2TEzQvPNvQLfKqw+JfNIvEGX+pLQ+CfBLIxqUVwVfsXYWoGHtRWrlLugSF0TX5ZuSk84wM4cNb0vYwoDigtnsU9eRqdbqkupUu1NH3A1N3PlIsu5mP-RcXyHEQNdbnwhgBcL7pphCcxqJ8oAAJSTEzSLTJcGIXoCnxhKfQOD4san2J002SyGOEJXvFsOW8QSJmoPksJoY3BKkfj2w0vZ9sLznP8lOwuAUDsJwWRlIE-5jC9iLh1lCPO3okSU7iqKfEJtvIRna5bF0jUlFi-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-mzU73rEh2AUKC2AIEsJ7yH0RylETCam2F+HZHRxQXTBMxEPdHrSuVrRuXrBCimwli0ieV0g83jE1iZF4wJHZDp1pSVRpFi1cg9mLA5zAOa0Zh4mR35zQEFEvyEQBRFAjG0R8glyxDxDuG2AEl3VQFNDqg2zy0TBJTVxVBHD2AjgA1122GenNUNzJUjGLkuUay5190LF2EElwJPAgj-VtHVE9n6yoLsjW2YMCRiRhnC3lRGGm2WyGDSyDHNjYLfVLFXW3j-ytFw0fB+G5Xc32xqT1xG1kSqUkIfDxE7n913iL33myXWDWkpSYze0vh1gVU+A2HCAAF1IgjFfAkAnATB44EA0B0gbBEh9QvRCh6IGAEBKBcFehttttrAkAUgQAAAVD4gAfRRlJNRnUEwFJIAFlaSQA4YoBkSGBUSXB0TMS0EwZCSI04BrRSSAAFUSUkl+SKJklktk9ADkygVw-EwkgAVQAGUX5BThSI02BgJGSFBQBmTBAUSyYpSYgMTKB1NEduSXBFSlhSS1BSSiSVTRT9BnBxS9TWSDSQBpSJwjRzT0BFSyQRTYQcgRTuQnTtSkSXTJT3SjTMSgtIpvSQBG95R-SaBAyHSQydSJS3TpSy4vTlBCTUYrQkyUzgytT0zwzMyozKBj1MQ4yAAZGIQswQIMx0kssM-UtNSMzAY091XMOMkkkCUkgAOQFKJNJP+zYDRDTNbNdPbOlO7JgDmDEAAConC9g5SXAhyRyqSIBrgwSlBiBbBZBmSXRET-AjAlQdS2AkgEB5A0h4YBl6hQSNI2AMgETiSySKStyaT6TrBeT+ShTfAmzrAlSVT-zST1TNSlBLSOhrS2BbT7TizIK-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-qqal8iEpAMgMgfwCgdsgoaEsYdy9ABapaugGIGgNavUS8rau676va6EsgQ63m8EuGSWty4S9ALy4EOUWQUSBoDwGgU4NAH4HypWmgfy1AEIMIdqugeW6WuACwfqjcnGaksof8soFGawDapOkAJgdmx4OwRUrQBCQJWE+UEoMW3kPYCE2y-i+y4WkAEq+27wQS+AWIO6mqt29c4cyk6k8OvOkAKO+UGO1aw6hOza3Kkasa9Ae+JGAECOuStgBARwHqlEXU4wZi2ARAQoEesIeONOjOr60al8u6gG3WtAWQVkwQPmvQfaiAWE3weEyGqciM6Ujc4+7cxcrYNc9AA87cpawco+2wbcxkzmnO6Wt+gu6wRwYu3wUurwCu1AKuwvXy2ulWiIAEZuv+oxNuju4cru7cnu0SPu0oAexO3K4e0e4zceyerzMe2e0WlegcRekW+erWqSu2h27e60FAPe12mZEh+wRM3Byh16oxN+i+5a2O+O5qu+uIfemZZ+x+V+s++Sz+vIQQVoX+uILgQBjy3a0Bg60yiBuAKB5i+K4weBnITOjSAIS8nSf+xIQR+gIxlwRwdwT28uPJ+USJoAA)

1. For adding the line on bar chart, you can provide `layer` config as an array inside the `spec` object and provide multiple marks for it.
2. Similarly, add `mark` config with value `text` inside the `layer`. So, that will help to add the labels.
3. A similar pie chart is added at the bottom but the values of this pie chart is achieved by multiplying it with a value. For example: 5. The pie chart gets disappeared because it share the same axis or we can say `theta` config. To fix that you need to add a `resolve` config. Check the documentation for [resolve](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/resolve.html) config.
4. The `selection` configuration given in this [tutorial](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/interactive_bar_select_highlight.html) has been added in the layer, where the mark `bar` is provided.
5. In vega or vega-lite, the data can be filtered using the `transform` config. Its use is somewhat similar to the `calculate` config which was used in your code. Check the documentation for [filter transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/filter.html).

Comment: Wahab, thank you very much for the response. It was a huge help. One odd thing that I have noticed is that the selection on bar chart and dimming the rest is not working in browser. You can see the following link where i dropped the code without any change and avoid any kind of styling. 
https://bahrikutlu.000webhostapp.com/vegalite/vegalitetest_stackoverflow.html

Comment: I have just noticed that using the dependencies that are noted on https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/usage/embed.html

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega@5.12.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-lite@4.13.1"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-embed@6.8.0"></script>

causing the highlight feature to not work. Instead, using the second option to get the latest version makes everything work. I was under the impression that the versions listed above are the latest versions.

Comment: yes, it can be a bug or some feature which is newly introduced not working.